# How to locate what produces sound in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to mute the sound coming from https://open.spotify.com/ website on specific times (using a script I made) in chrome.

I'm searching for the element which is actually producing the sound so I can deactivate/remove it or manipulate it somehow to do so and be able to turn it back on later. However, I couldn't locate what is producing the sound in the webpage.

I tried searching for and found no `<audio` / `<video` / `<iframe` / `.swf` / `.start(` in the page's source code. Is there any other way to produce sound with html in chrome?

Otherwise, I guess it's coming from a javascript loaded with the webpage. In the latter case, how can I find which script is the one producing sound? In addition, how can I locate where this specific one is called from in the webpage source code / manipulate it the way I want to?

Thanks

Comment: Sources tab in dev tools will list all resources (eg js,css,etc files) that have been loaded by the page

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes, I see that, but what should I search for in each script? Also, is there a way to search in all of them? And finally, in case I do find the specific script that plays the sound, how can I know what in the page is triggering it?

Comment: Seems Spotify is using WebPack framework. So Its unable to decode the exact thing without understanding it